# GDB python API - getting the python API of gdb to print the offending line number

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to use the gdb python API to write a few debugging macro to c code. But while testing the script I see that the interpretation errors in the script are reported without a line number.

For example

`(gdb) module show obj-template 0x7264b0 
"test-entry"
Python Exception <class 'IndexError'> list index out of range: 
Error occurred in Python command: list index out of range`

Here I can see that there is an IndexError, but the script does not say which is the line number, how do I get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the exception inside your script, at some proper position, and pretty print the exception and backtrace as you like.

I want to suggest you refer to some gdb plugin written in gdbpython, including [peda](https://github.com/longld/peda), [gef](https://github.com/hugsy/gef), [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg), etc. Such plugins have virtually used every feature of gdbpython, and contain very good practice for writing python gdb plugin. Robust gdbpython plugins usually have pretty-printer for python exceptions.

As an example, here is the backtrace pretty-printer of gef: (of course you cannot use it directly, since it contains too many gef internal functions)

```
def show_last_exception():
    """Display the last Python exception."""
    print("")
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print(" Exception raised ".center(80, horizontal_line))
    print("{}: {}".format(Color.colorify(exc_type.__name__, attrs="bold underline red"), exc_value))
    print(" Detailed stacktrace ".center(80, horizontal_line))
    for fs in traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)[::-1]:
        if PYTHON_MAJOR==2:
            filename, lineno, method, code = fs
        else:
            filename, lineno, method, code = fs.filename, fs.lineno, fs.name, fs.line

        print("""{} File "{}", line {:d}, in {}()""".format(down_arrow, Color.yellowify(filename),
                                                            lineno, Color.greenify(method)))
        print("   {}    {}".format(right_arrow, code))

    print(" Last 10 GDB commands ".center(80, horizontal_line))
    gdb.execute("show commands")
    print(" Runtime environment ".center(80, horizontal_line))
    print("* GDB: {}".format(gdb.VERSION))
    print("* Python: {:d}.{:d}.{:d} - {:s}".format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor,
                                                   sys.version_info.micro, sys.version_info.releaselevel))
    print("* OS: {:s} - {:s} ({:s}) on {:s}".format(platform.system(), platform.release(),
                                                    platform.architecture()[0],
                                                    " ".join(platform.dist())))
    print(horizontal_line*80)
    print("")
    return
```